# Killing Scripts and Style elements during Webscraping in Python

Tags: python, html, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using the below code to webscrape and kill scripts and style so that I only get text from webpage

```
    link= "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg"
    url = Request(link,headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/5.0'})
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # kill all script and style elements
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out

    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()

    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    print(text)
```

Example: Suppose the soup from website is

```
<ul><li>Technology entrepreneur</li><li>philanthropist</li></ul></div></td> 
</tr><tr><th scope="row">Years active</th><td>
```

I want it to print

```
Technology entrepreneur philanthropist Years active
```

whereas it is printing

```
Technology entrepreneurphilanthropistYears active
```

I want it to insert space wherever it is killing script and style elements. Any suggestions in the above code are appreciated. You can run the original url to check.

Answer (score 0):

After you extract the script-tags you could convert the html to a string and use a regex to substitute the tags.

This works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link= "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg"
r = requests.get(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/5.0'})
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") # feel free to use other parsers, e.g. html.parser, I use lxml as it's the fastest one...
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    script.extract()
html = str(soup)
html = re.sub('<.+?>', ' ', html)
html = " ".join(html.strip().split())
print(html)
```

Edited after it became clear to me what was really asked for...

Comment: There is random text like "document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace" which is getting removed by my code but not by this. It is only removing <> but not other scripts like the one I mentioned have came now.

Comment: Sorry. The * should be a plus I guess. Try it now.

Comment: Soup is like this
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="client-nojs" dir="ltr" lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Mark Zuckerberg - Wikipedia</title>
<script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace( /(^|\s)client-nojs(\s|$)/, "$1client-js$2" );</script>

Comment: After your code text is like Mark Zuckerberg - Wikipedia document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace( /(^|\s)client-nojs(\s|$)/, "$1client-js$2" ); (window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[])

Comment: Oh. I thought you were looking for a solution for one specific part of a soup. Not parsing the entire html. Of course the javascript-part will be interpreted as text.

Comment: Why do you want to extract the text of the page like this? If I understand what you're trying to achieve it's possible there a better way to achieve this than the way you're going right now...

Comment: @jlaur- I want to extract text from the webpage, given the link. Can you please share the better way that will solve this problem. I will use that.

Comment: I got that part. But ALL of the text or only certain parts of the text?

Comment: All text in the webpage (header, body, side text everything)